# VMWare bridged VM to 2 different physical networks

Tags: bridge, vmware-workstation, virtual-network, virtual-network-interface

I am using VMware Workstation 17 Pro. In my Windows based host machine, I am running a linux based VM which needs to be connected 2 different physical interface of host.

As far as I found, having 2 bridged network interface for same VM is possible if you are using vmware workstation. But when I configured 2 bridged network, each one for a physical interface of host machine, I see that VM is taking both IP address from the same physical network.

I configured 2 bridged VMnet in Virtual Network Editor. Each one for a dedicated physical network.
[image: VMNet cfg]

Then I configured VM, add 2 network adapter in bridged mode, and I expect to see 2 different IP addresses comes from physical networks

- one of them must be 192.168.1.x
- the other one must belong to subnet 214 like 192.168.214.x , since this physical network has a static IP belongs to 214 subnet.

[image: VM Overview]

As you see, both network adapters seem to bridged the same physical interface, even if I configured both physical interface to bridging.

I don't see any other configuration missing on VMWare side and do not want to create a custom network and handle all port forwarding to get a bridged network manually by myself.

Any idea to solve would be appreciated :)